# How to write a Matlab function that when given a single cell array of strings, returns a structure array with the same strings in alphabetical order?

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting

I'm sure there may be a matlab function to do this but I'm required to write my own. As the title says, I need to write a function which when given a single cell array of strings, returns a structure array, containing the same strings but in alphabetical order. Furthermore, the 'count' fields must contain the number of times that that particular string has occurred eg

> > z=myfunction({'bag','dig','bag'})

ans =

```
 str: 'bag'
 count = 2
```

Ideally, the method should have an expected number of comparisons for n strings of O(n log n)

Comment: Is this question still open? Have you tried anything yourself in the meantime?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't want to use standard functions like `sort` or `unique` this is not an easy question. Furthermore it is more about math then about programming.

If you just want to practice programming, try implementing something simple like *bubble sort*.

This will not achieve O(n log n) however, if you really want that look into *merge sort* for example.

Several options are explained roughly [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Efficient_sorts), and with a bit of searching it should not be hard to find what you need.